# Vim, practical usage example

Tags: vim

While I mostly use Sublime Text (with the Vintageous plugin) I'm trying to adopt Vim-style practices into my workflow. As you might expect, I'd like to learn how to more quickly jump around a document to edit its content.

For example, let's say I want to jump around and edit the ID values in a JSON file or perhaps jump from the first line of the document down to edit the first name of Gale Gomez.

I understand some of the basic commands like 'change inside quotes' (ci") or 'change word' (cw), I'm hoping to get better at page navigation.

Thoughts or suggestions?

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "firstName": "Jayne",
    "lasttName": "Norris",
    "email": "jaynenorris@talae.com"
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "firstName": "Gale",
    "lasttName": "Gomez",
    "email": "galegomez@talae.com"
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "firstName": "Garner",
    "lasttName": "Crane",
    "email": "garnercrane@talae.com"
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "firstName": "Gill",
    "lasttName": "Carter",
    "email": "gillcarter@talae.com"
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "firstName": "Evans",
    "lasttName": "Douglas",
    "email": "evansdouglas@talae.com"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To jump to the next ID and edit it:

```
/"id<return>3wcw
```

(searches for string *"id*, goes forward 3 words, then edits the next word, which is the ID's value)

To edit another ID:

```
n3wcw
```

(repeats the last search with “n”, then same as before)

Go to the first line of the document:

```
gg
```

Change first name of Gale Gomez:

```
/Gale<return>cw
```

(searches for “Gale”, then edits it)

Comment: Ahhhh! I see what's going on here. Thank you!

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat but I'd change the search to `/"id": \zs`. This way you are already positioned at the word you'd like to change and the `n3wcw` can be reduced to `ncw`.

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget `*` to search the word under the cursor (for example `id` in your case), then `n` for next occurrence, `N` for previous occurrence.

`#` is the same as `*`, only it searches backward. Actually, I never use that.

If you press `/` and then `<UP>` and `<DOWN>`, then `<CR>`, you can select and repeat one of your previous searches.

And sometimes when a search hits the last line of the window you may wish to type `zz` to scroll the window so that the current line will be in the middle of it and you will see some lines below.

Also, you can press `%` while over an opening/closing parenthesis to jump to the corresponding closing/opening parenthesis.

Comment: In Sublime Text, the / <up> or <down> option doesn't work but I see what you're trying to demonstrate. Much appreciated.